# Meaning of a negative "started at" time in Chrome DevTools

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

When inspecting a request in Chrome DevTools, I am seeing that the Queued time of the request happened at "0" but that the request was "started" at -154ms. I assumed that all requests must first be queued before they can actually be made (the started at time), so what would cause the request to start before it was queued?

Am I misunderstanding what these two numbers mean?

When watching events via the remote debugging port, I also see that the monotonic timestamp of the request being sent (via the [`requestTime`](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Network#type-ResourceTiming) associated with the [`Response`](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Network#type-Response)) is before the monotonic timestamp of the [`requestWillBeSent`](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Network/#event-requestWillBeSent) event for the same request.

[image]

For other resources in the page load, I see parity between the queued and start times:

[image]

Comment: have you ever figured this out?

Comment: @romanm Unfortunately I never did :(. I went ahead and added a bounty to try to get some eyes on it

Comment: in my case, both the Queued and Started values were negative. Turned out to be some sort of cached request. Closing the browser and rebuilding my application got rid of the entry in dev tools. Probably doesn't apply to you though, good luck.

Comment: It's been three years. Can you reproduce it with the newest version of Chrome?

Comment: its a bug, it says so in this chrome docs thing [here](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/network/reference/)